# .text in BeautifulSoup prints the data/info twice

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I started using BeautifulSoup and was trying to understand the difference between 
text and string attributes of the soup object. Here is the html code i am using:-

```
    html_doc = """
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>1.0 SOME TEXT</td>
                <td>
                    <p>2.0 SOME TEXT</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>3.1 SOME</p>
                    <p>3.2 TEXT</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

and this is what i have done:-

```
soup = bs(html_doc, 'html.parser')
tr = soup.find('tr')
children = tr.findChildren()
```

Now if I use .text with like I have done here:-

```
for child in children:
print(child.text)
```

The output is:-

```
1.0 SOME TEXT

2.0 SOME TEXT

2.0 SOME TEXT

3.1 SOME
3.2 TEXT

3.1 SOME
3.2 TEXT
```

But if I use .string attribute this is the output:-

```
None
1.0 SOME TEXT
None
2.0 SOME TEXT
None
3.1 SOME
3.2 TEXT
```

Now, i understand the 'none' and absence of text for the  tags that has no

tag and no text/info/data but i dont understand the why .text in BeautifulSoup prints the data/info twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `.text` will get you the text parsed text no matter if the string is directly on the node or in a childNode, but on the other hand the `.string` will go like this "If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None:"

```
print(soup.html.string)
# None
```

Read here more about the use of `.string` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string